# Get common data based on multiple fields in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I don't know if the question title is so clear, but here is my question:

I had table UsersMovements which contains Users along with their movements

UsersMovements:

```
ID
UserID
MovementID
Comments
```

I need help looking for a query which would give me if users 1, 2 & 3 had been in a common MovementID, knowing that I had know what is the MovementID

The real case is that I want to see if those X users which I would select been in an area (in a limited interval, assuming I had date/Time in the table)

Thank you

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (no images.) [mcve]

Comment: You'll probably end up using GROUP BY and HAVING.

Answer (score 0):

The following returns all movement ids that have all three users:

```
select movementid
from usermovements
where userid in (1, 2, 3)
group by movementid
having count(distinct userid) = 3
```